# How to use text prompt in bot framework 4?

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

I am changing a code which has been implemented in Framework 3 to the Framework v4.

The use case is like the following:
The user enters something like "I am searching for XY".
We determine the intent, if it is MyIntent, we search the input in a database, and if we find it, we show a text to the user like "I found your search item in the database".
Then, we show another text (a follow up question) saying something like "What is the name of the department?".

The user can enter something and it will be processed. BUT the point is that at this point, the user can again say "I am searching for ABC". That is, the user can ignore that the chatbot has asked a follow up question and enter a normal input. And the chatbot is also expected to process it as a normal one.

In the meantime, if at the beginning the entered item is not found in the database, we want to return something like "sorry, I couldn't find it in the database. Is there anything else that I can help you?"

I mean, I have a condition inside this intent.

Previously, this part of the text prompt has been implemented simply by:

```
       PromptDialog.Text(context, answerMe, "What is the name of the department?", $"Sorry I don't understand.", 3);
```

In which `context` is of type `IDialogContext`and `answerMe` is a method like the following:

```
 private async Task answerMe(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> res1)
    {
        string text = await res1;
        if (Functions.IsCancelList(text, CancelOptionsEqual, CancelOptionsContain))
        {
            await CancelDialog(context, "Empty");
        }
        else
        {
           
            string s = text;
            bool str=Functions.isText(s);

           ...
            await CallMethod(context, text);
        }

    }
```

Now, my class is like the following:

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using XYT.Models;
using XYT.Services;

namespace XYZ.Dialogs
{
    public class MyMainDialog: MainDialogBase
    {
        private readonly ICommonBotServices _commonBotServices;

        public MyMainDialog(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<MainDialogBase> logger, ICommonBotServices commonBotServices, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, UserState userState)
            : base(configuration, logger, serviceProvider, userState)
        {
            _commonBotServices = commonBotServices;
        }

        protected override async Task<DialogTurnResult> ProcessInput(WaterfallStepContext wtrflCntxt, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
           
            var result = await _commonBotServices.Luis.RecognizeAsync<MyRecognizer>(wtrflCntxt.Context, cancellationToken);
            var intent = result.TopIntent();

            switch (intent.intent)
            {
                
                case MyRecognizer.Intent.MyIntent:
                  
                    await wtrflCntxt.Context.SendActivityAsync($"Let me search");

                    String answer = $"I found it in the database,...";
                           
                  await wtrflCntxt.Context.SendActivityAsync(answer);

//??? to be implemented
                 
                    return await wtrflCntxt.EndDialogAsync();
       }
    }
}
```

I don't know how I should implement the use case. I don't think the waterfall dialog is the correct one for me.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would take a look at the docs on [Migrating from V3 to V4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/conversion-core?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), if you haven't.

There's a lot of different ways you can go about accomplishing what you want, so it's difficult for me to provide an exact answer. Generally, I would say that Waterfall Dialogs are the way to go.

If you go with Waterfall Dialogs, it sounds like you'd need to handle interruptions, so that if:

1. The user asks "I am searching for XY"
2. The bot starts the Waterfall Dialog and prompts, "What is the name of the department?"
3. The user ignores the prompt and asks, "I am searching for ABC"

...it needs to be able to interrupt the dialog. For this, I'd look at the [Core Bot Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot). It handles interrupts via the [Cancel and Help Dialog](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Dialogs/CancelAndHelpDialog.cs). Basically, all user input first goes to this dialog. If the user says "cancel" or "help", it iterrupts the current dialog and handles those intents. You would likely do something simliar with `MyIntent`, instead of Cancel and Help. *Note, however that this sample doesn't use LUIS for this. You'd need to have LUIS look for intents and then interrupt based on those*

If you're looking for something more flexible, you likely want to consider [Adaptive Dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-adaptive-dialog-introduction?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). Waterfall Dialogs are very programmatic; `if user says "X" in this circumstance, do "Y"`. Adaptive Dialogs are much more flexible in that it doesn't really matter what the user is currently doing--if they say something with a matching intent, it starts the appropriate dialog. I think this is more what you're looking for, but we don't have migration documentation for it. [Here mare several Adaptive Dialog samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/adaptive-dialog)

[Composer](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer), a GUI-based bot builder, is based on Adaptive Dialogs and you may even prefer that.